# gatling combining transform with jsonpath

Tags: transform, jsonpath, gatling

I'm trying to extract a security_token from this response :

```
{}&&{"containers":{"userID":"p8admin","connected":true,"desktop":"icm"},
     "userid":"p8admin",
     "user_displayname": "p8admin",
     "security_token":"-1829880900612241155",
     "messages":[{"adminResponse":null,
                  "moreInformation":null,
                  "explanation":null,
                  "number":"0",
                  "userResponse":null,
                  "text":"p8admin connect\u00e9."
                 }]
     }
```

I've tried combining  transform and jsonPath :

```
.check(bodyString.transform(_.split("&&")(1)).jsonPath("&.security_token").saveAs("security_token"))
```

but i get this error :

```
value jsonPath is not a member of com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.check.MatcherCheckBuilder
```

Let me know if there is a simple way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on checks:

> This API provides a dedicated DSL for chaining the following steps:
>
> 1. defining the check
> 2. extracting
> 3. transforming
> 4. verifying
> 5. saving

Since the response isn't valid JSON, you'll need to use `bodyString` as the type. You can then transform and then save, but you can't go back to step 1. You can parse the value you need out of the JSON during the `transform` step.

As Stéphane pointed out, the easiest way to get the value is to use a `regex` check and extract the security_token value directly, as long as you don't need the rest of your JSON object for any logic.

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to use a regex here.

Comment: Well i'm not found of regex and i'll need to extract other information from this kind of response later, i'm trying something like that :`.transform(JSON.parseFull(_.toString.substring(4)).security_token)` but as is just moved to 2.0.0-M3a, transform doesn't takes a String anymore. And by the way i'm really not familiar with the scala syntax, sorry fot that.

Comment: Looking here : [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gatling/qErj87jujGQ/2VPUmW83n5AJ] it seems easier to externalize it : `val extractToken = (transformation: Option[String]) => {
    val stringResponse =  transformation.toString.substring(4)
    val jsonResponse = JSON.parseFull(stringResponse)
    jsonResponse.security_token
  }` but i'm getting an error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I used the `regex()` function like this :

```scala
.check(regex(""""security_token":"(.*)",""").saveAs("security_token"))
```